# Kindle - Google Fonts Not Loading

Tags: wordpress, fonts, kindle-fire

I can't figure out why my google fonts won't load on a Kindle Fire 2012 7". I see other sites have their google fonts work on this device, but for some reason my sites' fonts do not load.

how fonts should look ([desktop](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1885149/Image%20Files/kindle/desktop.png))

how they look on my [Kindle](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1885149/Image%20Files/kindle/kindle.png)

Any advice?

[My Site.](http://filmgarb.com)

Answer (score 0):

I've loaded your website on  1st, 2nd, and 3rd generation Kindle Fire 7" devices using the built-in SILK browser. I'm not seeing a font problem. Can you be more specific or provide a URL that exhibits the problem every time?

Comment: Interesting...I load the website on my Kindle Fire 7" and my google fonts aren't loading. It seems the Kindle is swapping the google fonts for basic sans-serif font. I have updated the original post to include screenshots - is the desktop version fonts what you are seeing?

Comment: Did you resolve this - I've just bought one for testing and instantly noticed that fontface doesn't seem to work everywhere.